# I want to map my organisation drawings template as default catia v5 template

Tags: vba, scripting, drawing, catia

I want to map my organisation drawings  templates (standard template) as default catia v5 template.
For example,;;;

File >>new>>drawing>>

One pop up will come to choose drawing template  size
A0, A1, A2, A3,A4..

Once we choose any one of them

Then existing standard organisation .CATdrawing template (with title block) Should come.

Please guide!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You want to achieve this per a macro (and perhaps own userform)? Or lock the option to use _new_ for drawings and use _new from_ for drawings only.

Comment: I tried to set my drawings as default drawing of Catia v5 but no luck, then tried to do CATscript, is there any simple way to map my custom created drawings in catia v5 as default drawings

Comment: I suggest you to lock _New_ for drawings (in the options) and use only _new from_ from your templates

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to lock file>>new option in catia v5?

Comment: Options > mechanical Design > Drafting > Administration